# How can I cut top off of CSS glow effect with box-shadow?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a nice CSS glow effect with the following div:

```css
.darkglow {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 450px 450px #000000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="darkglow"></div>
```

How can I cut the top off of the effect so that the display does not show a complete circle, but rather a half moon style display?  I have tried various fixes with `overflow: hidden` but this does not seem to clip the effect.

Comment: Not sure what you mean; it shows 1/4th of a circle to me.

Comment: Have you tried negative values in place of the zeros in box-shadow? Just guessing, I'm on my phone so I can't test this

Comment: JSfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/BTg46/ needs further clarification as it does not explain the problem.

Comment: The way you have your code set up is confusing... it is positioned top left of the screen, so we only see a quarter of the glow effect anyway... if you center the div to the page the top will be cut off by the top of the page anyway.  is that all you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css, play with the properties `border-radius` and `box-shadow`:

```
.darkglow:after {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius:250px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 125px 250px #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hhvv5/

Comment: this helps, but I am looking for a hard line across the horizon that hides the upper half of the circle.

Comment: all you have to do is play with `:after` and `:before` in your css, you can do almost anything...

Comment: Still I only get to see 1/4th of a circle

Comment: I also have a margin which is pushing the full glow into view.

Comment: Could you not just use a gradient rather than a box-shadow?

Comment: @Paulie_D the effect I am after is just to display a hard horizontal line with a radial shadow below it.  I think that box shadow will work better for this if I can figure out how to clip the hard horizontal line.

Comment: Boc-shadow doesn't work that way (AFAIK), I do think a radial gradient would be the way to go.

Comment: @Paulie_D ok, can you please show me an example of how I could do this with radial gradient?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BTg46/2/ ...but without a proper look at what you are trying to do (with your current structure) it's hard to help further.

Comment: @Presto why don't you just print an image of what you're trying to reach?

Comment: @Paulie_D that is what I needed, thanks.  Is there any way I can make the gradient fade to white on the left right and bottom so that the only hard edge is the top?